# Eliminate sub-query from mysql view

Tags: mysql, view

I have a query that I am trying to build a view off of. The query below works as I would expect it to, but it has a sub-query, so mysql won't let me build a view off it. I'll start by saying I'm still relatively new to sql queries, so I am a little lost when trying to refactor this into a query without a sub-query. I have seen a few Q/As on here where more experienced users have helped eliminate sub-queries such as this, and I was hoping someone might be able to make some suggestions for me. I have also seen the suggestion of doing multiple views, and then combining them, but this feels less clean to me, and I'd rather not do it if someone can see a means of eliminating the sub-query here. Generic advice on eliminating sub-queries would be great so I have a better idea what to look for, as well as a more specific answer to the problem at hand.

### The query:

```
(SELECT
    `user_id`,`operations`.`name` AS `operation`, 
    `objectables`.`objectable_id` AS `objectable_id`,
    `objectables`.`objectable_type` AS `objectable_type`,
    sha2(concat(`operations`.`name`,
                `objectables`.`objectable_type`,
                `objectables`.`objectable_id`),
                256) AS `access_hash` 
 FROM 
 (
   (SELECT
     `users`.`id` as `user_id`,
     `ace_user`.`ace_id` as `ace_id` 
    FROM
     `users` 
      LEFT JOIN `ace_user` ON ((`ace_user`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`))
   )
   UNION
   (SELECT
     `users`.`id` as `user_id`, `ace_id`
    FROM (
      ((`users`
      LEFT JOIN `role_user` ON ((`role_user`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`)))
      LEFT JOIN `permission_role` ON ((`permission_role`.`role_id` = `role_user`.`role_id`)))
      LEFT JOIN `ace_permission` ON ((`ace_permission`.`permission_id` = `permission_role`.`permission_id`))
    )
 )
) as `all_aces`
LEFT JOIN `aces` ON ((`aces`.`id` = `all_aces`.`ace_id`))
LEFT JOIN `operations` ON ((`operations`.`id` = `aces`.`operation_id`))
LEFT JOIN `objectables` ON ((`objectables`.`ace_id` = `all_aces`.`ace_id`)))
```

I apologize for the slightly convoluted mess of a query that's above. In a nutshell what I am trying to do is make a view that summarizes all the access a user has. A user can be granted access either via direct assignment of an ACE (Access control entry) or via a Role, which has certain permissions associated with it, which are linked to their own set of ACEs. ACEs are in turn linked to the objects they grant permission to. I'm trying to make a view that shows all of these, along with a hash of object,operation etc for quicker hasAccess() checks. Hopefully this helps make sense of my messy query above.

Thanks in advance for any and all help!
-Wally

Comment: Hope you don't mind, I worked on the indentation to make it a little more visually parseable at a glance.

Comment: Oh god that's so much cleaner. Thank you!

Comment: Use a second view for the subquery.  That always works.

Comment: I had wanted to avoid using a 2nd view, though in retrospect having a view for the all_aces section would be beneficial for other applications. I Actually am going to go down this road for this problem, but I don't know that it will always be the route I'd like to take. As such, generic advice for avoiding/eliminating sub-queries (without using another view) would still be greatly appreciated.